# How to use react-router-dom v5 render props using Typscript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I tried to convert a React app from Javascript to Typescript from code in youtube tutorial.

```
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
import './assets/boxicons-2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css';
import './App.scss';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import Routes from './config/Routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        render={props => (
          <>
            <Header {...props} />
            <Routes />
            <Footer />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I got error at this part
[image]

This is my Header code

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './header.scss';
import logo from '../../assets/tmovie.png';

const headerNav = [
    {
        display: 'Home',
        path: '/'
    },
    {
        display: 'Movies',
        path: '/movie'
    },
    {
        display: 'TV Series',
        path: '/tv'
    }
];

const Header = () => {

    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const headerRef:any = useRef(null);

    const active = headerNav.findIndex(e => e.path === pathname);

    useEffect(() => {
        const shrinkHeader = () => {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
                headerRef.current.classList.add('shrink');
            } else {
                headerRef.current.classList.remove('shrink');
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', shrinkHeader);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', shrinkHeader);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div ref={headerRef} className="header">
            <div className="header__wrap container">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src={logo} alt="" />
                    <Link to="/">tMovies</Link>
                </div>
                <ul className="header__nav">
                    {
                        headerNav.map((e, i) => (
                            <li key={i} className={`${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                                <Link to={e.path}>
                                    {e.display}
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

I use some package

@testing-library/jest-dom: 5.16.5

@testing-library/react: 14.0.0

@testing-library/user-event: 14.4.3

axios: 1.4.0

prop-types: 15.8.1

query-string: 8.1.0

react: 18.2.0

react-dom: 18.2.0

react-router-dom: 5.3.0

sass: 1.62.1

swiper: 6.8.4

More detail you can see my json
Here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
}
```

How to use `Route` `render` prop in Typescript?

Comment: Please put the error details

Comment: We can't address issues with code we can't see and errors we don't know. Please [edit] to include what errors you are seeing, including any code stack traces if you have them. Can you also include your package.json file so we can see what specific version of `react-router-dom` you are using?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just woke up this morning and posted the question when I got to sleep so i just read the comments

Comment: What props, if any, is the `Header` component expecting? Can you share also the `Header` component code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Header` component isn't actually consuming any props:

```
const Header = () => { // <-- NO PROPS
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const headerRef:any = useRef(null);

  const active = headerNav.findIndex(e => e.path === pathname);

  ...
```

`Header` is using the React hooks that have supplanted the older [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), in this case, specifically the `useLocation` hook to access what was previously the `props.location` prop value. Using the React hooks is now the preferred method.

Since no props consumed you should clean up the route and remove the passing through of route props.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        render={() => (
          <>
            <Header />
            <Routes />
            <Footer />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Or as a minor optimization, render the `Header`, `Routes`, and `Footer` directly since they are rendered by a pathless route and unconditionally rendered anyway.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Routes />
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass `...props` as an attribute here, because there is types mismatch between this file and header component, as mentioned in the error (history, location, match, and staticContext). You need to set the proper type in header component (e.g., extend intrinsicAttributes), as:

```js
interface HeaderProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  history: History<unknown>;
  location: Location<unknown>;
  match: match<{ [x: string]: string | undefined; }>;
  staticContext?: StaticContext | undefined;
}

function Header(props: HeaderProps) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: History<unknow>, Location<unknown>, match, and StaticContext is not generic

Comment: @MindMon That is why we need to see the code for Header component as well, this I've written based on your error.

Comment: are you using library ? I tried in my code, think it not inside typescript

Comment: No, its inside the Header component. If you are following a YT tutorial, I'd stay on course first.